# Android get url from browser

Tags: android, url

I am try to open my app on url click and get value from it, url looks like : path.com/item?key=value

in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="path.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/item"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

but

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData(); 
data.getPathSegments();
Log.d("TAG", "param is:" + params.get(0);
```

returns: param is:item /item . how to get key=value or full url

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did recently in my app

Use following intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="<SCHEME_NAME>" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your URL use following

for Chrome

```
window.location = "intent://item?key=value#Intent;scheme=<SCHEME_NAME>;package=<APP_PACKAGE>;";`
```

other bowsers

```
window.location = "<SCHEME_NAME>://item?key=value";
```

In the Activity class use following

```
String uriPath = getIntent().getDataString();
```

uriPath will have string "item?key=value" which you can parse based on patterns.

You can Modify the "item?key=value" in your JS to send only value if required.
Do experiment on this.

Follow the link for more 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 1):

If the intent was to visit a URL (i.e., `intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW`), then `intent.getData()` will return that URL.

```
Uri data = intent.getData();
String path = data.getPath();
```

Comment: nope, data.getPath returns /profile, but data.toString() returns link, I am idiot :(

Answer (score 1):

To get the full Uri string, you can do toString() on the Uri. But I would advise against that. Most likely, what you want is already in a method of Uri.

If you want the full path, use `getPath()`. If you want the full Uri as a String, `toString()`. If you want a specific query parameter, `getQueryParameter(String key)`. If you want the full query string, `getQuery()`. If you want the keys you got in the query parameter, `getQueryParameterNames()`.

There's a lot more. Those are the ones that I think might be useful to you based on your question.

You can, of course, do your own parsing, but most of the time it's unnecessary and error prone.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html