# Share Url from browser to other apps in android

Tags: android, android-browser

I am working on a website and the requirement is that user's can share a page, link or image

I want to make a share button on my webpage which allows user to share a link, image, etc via the apps installed in the user's phone. How can I achieve that.

It's should be like the share panel as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain more. As I understood your question, You can use FCM to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Loks like you want something like this:
[Android get url from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205502/android-get-url-from-browser)

Also look through this link
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear about the question. But from what I understand, you want to share a particular page from your app, so it can be visited using a shareable link.

I think you're looking for is [Deep Linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html).

---

Update: HTML Sharing Buttons: https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/for/website

Comment: I want to share the link of my webpage through the apps installed on the user's phone like, Whatsapp, facebook, twitter, etc. Please read the updated question description.

Comment: No, I need something like this - https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/ , check the share button in this post

Comment: The share button on page is literally a Tweet Button. The link I shared with you has that functionality. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [Web Share API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) is what you are looking for.

It allows you to initiate the share intent via javascript. Android then displays the exact same share popup as in native apps.

Example from MDN:

```
navigator.share({
  title: document.title,
  text: 'Hello World',
  url: 'https://developer.mozilla.org',
});
```